# Given-When-Then with multiple possible Thens?

Tags: bdd

I just discovered the concept of BDD and I'm trying to understand how to write user stories the right way. Suppose I need to test my application against some external state that may not be possible to completely stipulate via `Given`, such that instead of a single `Then` I might have multiple:

```
Given [State]
When [Some Action]
  And [Some Other Action]
Then [Outcome A]
  And [Outcome A']
  Or [Outcome B]
  And [Outcome B']
```

Is this a reasonable story to tell in BDD? In my case, `A` and `B` are both reasonable, expected outcomes given the state and actions, and they are the only acceptable outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system has non-deterministic behaviour, then this is perfectly appropriate.

However, computer systems have deterministic behaviour, so if you're developing software (rather than using BDD on, say, a human system of interaction), then you probably want to specify it more precisely.

You can always mock out or write your own stubs for the context in the Givens. For instance, in the Tetris game we originally used to develop JBehave, I replaced the random seed used in the real game with a known seed for the purposes of the scenario. I was then able to add lines like:

> Given our current shape is a "T"
>   And the next shape is an "S" <-- which I can know because it's a fixed seed

You can do something similar with dates, third-party systems, existing production systems, etc.

I would therefore expect you to have two scenarios:

> Given [State]
>   **And [State leading to A]**
>   When [Some Action]
>     And [Some Other Action]
>   Then [Outcome A]
>     And [Outcome A']

and similarly for B:

> Given [State]
>   **And [State leading to B]**
>   When [Some Action]
>     And [Some Other Action]
>   Then [Outcome B]
>     And [Outcome B']

Conversations around the different contexts in which the system works and how they lead to different outcomes are at the heart of BDD. This is what helps to illustrate the system's *behaviour*.

However, if your system really is so far out of your control that you can't use it deterministically, and if your chosen tool supports using "or", then automating your way is fine. I would still be as specific as possible in your conversations, though. There *will be* a context which means that you code for Outcome B for that context instead of Outcome A; otherwise you could just make Outcome A your only outcome, then say, "Job done".

Answer (score 0):

If is readable, understandable and cannot be misconstrued then do whatever you want.